# Eclipse Refactoring (Renaming) throws ExecutionException caused by NullpoinerException

Tags: eclipse, refactoring

While coding yesterday I stumbled over a sudden error occuring in my Eclipse IDE. I wanted to rename a variable and pressed (as I should and I am used to) ALT + SHIFT + R. This however opened *Run* in the toolbar. I thought ok maybe I pressed wrong keys but this error kept happening.

I then tried to restart Eclipse, reload the project (deleted it but not the content on the disk and loaded it again by importing) and also deleted the workspace but the error still occured.

Then I thought maybe the installation is somehow broken so I reinstalled Eclipse (btw. I am using the latest *06-2020* Version). This did not help either though...

After a lot of using Google I also found the following articles this question might seem to be similar to

- [Can't refactor rename in Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11379808/cant-refactor-rename-in-eclipse)
- [Eclipse refactoring fails -> Keeps throwing exceptions!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5307552/eclipse-refactoring-fails-keeps-throwing-exceptions)
- https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/375178/

but the suggestions in these did not work for me.

What I saw while browsing the Error-log was that a lot of errors occured while using the rename function. I hope someone has a suggestion how to fix this because also renaming with mouse doesn't work any more.

Some more details:

- Error suddenly occured > It worked all the time and suddenly stopped working without (at least me) knowing about any changes
- I am using Windows 10 with OpenJ9 JDK14 as the default JDK an JRE so eclipse also uses this JRE

Errors:

```
!ENTRY org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench 4 0 2020-08-22 09:57:49.697
!MESSAGE Execution exception for: ParameterizedCommand(Command(org.eclipse.jdt.ui.edit.text.java.rename.element,Rename - Refactoring ,
        Rename the selected element,
        Category(org.eclipse.jdt.ui.category.refactoring,Refactor - Java,Java Refactoring Actions,true),
        org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchHandlerServiceHandler@bcbec4c7,
        ,,true),null) in 
    context chain: WorkbenchContext -> TrimmedWindowImpl (IDEWindow) Context -> PerspectiveImpl (org.eclipse.jdt.ui.JavaPerspective) Context -> PartImpl (org.eclipse.e4.ui.compatibility.editor)  removeOnHide org.eclipse.jdt.ui.CompilationUnitEditorContext
!STACK 0

org.eclipse.core.commands.ExecutionException: While executing the action, an exception occurred
    at org.eclipse.jface.commands.ActionHandler.execute(ActionHandler.java:126)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.handlers.E4HandlerProxy.execute(E4HandlerProxy.java:97)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor46.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.MethodRequestor.execute(MethodRequestor.java:58)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.invokeUsingClass(InjectorImpl.java:319)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.invoke(InjectorImpl.java:253)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.contexts.ContextInjectionFactory.invoke(ContextInjectionFactory.java:173)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.commands.internal.HandlerServiceHandler.execute(HandlerServiceHandler.java:156)
    at org.eclipse.core.commands.Command.executeWithChecks(Command.java:488)
    at org.eclipse.core.commands.ParameterizedCommand.executeWithChecks(ParameterizedCommand.java:487)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.commands.internal.HandlerServiceImpl.executeHandler(HandlerServiceImpl.java:213)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.bindings.keys.KeyBindingDispatcher.executeCommand(KeyBindingDispatcher.java:308)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.bindings.keys.KeyBindingDispatcher.press(KeyBindingDispatcher.java:584)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.bindings.keys.KeyBindingDispatcher.processKeyEvent(KeyBindingDispatcher.java:653)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.bindings.keys.KeyBindingDispatcher.filterKeySequenceBindings(KeyBindingDispatcher.java:443)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.bindings.keys.KeyBindingDispatcher.access$2(KeyBindingDispatcher.java:386)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.bindings.keys.KeyBindingDispatcher$KeyDownFilter.handleEvent(KeyBindingDispatcher.java:96)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:89)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.filterEvent(Display.java:1248)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1036)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1061)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1046)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.traverse(Control.java:4257)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.translateMnemonic(Control.java:4107)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Composite.translateMnemonic(Composite.java:1240)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Composite.translateMnemonic(Composite.java:1243)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.translateMnemonic(Control.java:4125)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.translateMnemonic(Display.java:4824)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.filterMessage(Display.java:1266)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3626)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$5.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1158)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:338)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1047)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.E4Workbench.createAndRunUI(E4Workbench.java:155)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.lambda$3(Workbench.java:658)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$$Lambda$201/0000000000000000.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:338)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:557)
    at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:154)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:150)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:203)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:137)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:107)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:401)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:255)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:657)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:594)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1447)

Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.corext.dom.LinkedNodeFinder.getAssociatedRecordComponentNode(LinkedNodeFinder.java:68)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.corext.dom.LinkedNodeFinder$BindingFinder.visit(LinkedNodeFinder.java:334)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.core.dom.SimpleName.accept0(SimpleName.java:198)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.core.dom.ASTNode.accept(ASTNode.java:2971)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.core.dom.ASTNode.acceptChild(ASTNode.java:3019)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.core.dom.QualifiedName.accept0(QualifiedName.java:163)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.core.dom.ASTNode.accept(ASTNode.java:2971)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.core.dom.ASTNode.acceptChild(ASTNode.java:3019)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.core.dom.InfixExpression.accept0(InfixExpression.java:356)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.core.dom.ASTNode.accept(ASTNode.java:2971)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.core.dom.ASTNode.acceptChild(ASTNode.java:3019)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.core.dom.IfStatement.accept0(IfStatement.java:181)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.core.dom.ASTNode.accept(ASTNode.java:2971)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.core.dom.ASTNode.acceptChildren(ASTNode.java:3042)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.core.dom.Block.accept0(Block.java:128)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.core.dom.ASTNode.accept(ASTNode.java:2971)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.core.dom.ASTNode.acceptChild(ASTNode.java:3019)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.core.dom.MethodDeclaration.accept0(MethodDeclaration.java:698)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.core.dom.ASTNode.accept(ASTNode.java:2971)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.core.dom.ASTNode.acceptChildren(ASTNode.java:3042)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.core.dom.TypeDeclaration.accept0(TypeDeclaration.java:447)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.core.dom.ASTNode.accept(ASTNode.java:2971)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.core.dom.ASTNode.acceptChildren(ASTNode.java:3042)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.core.dom.CompilationUnit.accept0(CompilationUnit.java:258)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.core.dom.ASTNode.accept(ASTNode.java:2971)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.corext.dom.LinkedNodeFinder.findByBinding(LinkedNodeFinder.java:145)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.corext.dom.LinkedNodeFinder.findByNode(LinkedNodeFinder.java:165)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.refactoring.reorg.RenameLinkedMode.start(RenameLinkedMode.java:234)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.refactoring.actions.RenameJavaElementAction.run(RenameJavaElementAction.java:240)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.refactoring.actions.RenameJavaElementAction.doRun(RenameJavaElementAction.java:174)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.refactoring.actions.RenameJavaElementAction.run(RenameJavaElementAction.java:153)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.ui.actions.RenameAction.run(RenameAction.java:121)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.ui.actions.SelectionDispatchAction.dispatchRun(SelectionDispatchAction.java:278)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.ui.actions.SelectionDispatchAction.run(SelectionDispatchAction.java:252)
    at org.eclipse.jface.action.Action.runWithEvent(Action.java:474)
    at org.eclipse.jface.commands.ActionHandler.execute(ActionHandler.java:121)
    ... 53 more
```

Comment: Looks like [this bug](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=564329) marked as fixed in 4.17M1

Comment: Thanks. Using the version of eclipse you suggested fixed the problem! If you post an answer with this comment I can accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This looks like Eclipse bug [564329](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=564329) which is marked as fixed in Eclipse core 4.17 M1 (Milestone 1). So this fix will be in the 2020-09 release scheduled for September 2020.

Answer (score 0):

Temporary fix:  Window > Preferences > Java Compiler > turn off "Enable preview features for Java 14". Enable the "Use default compliance settings".

[Enable preview features setting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tnosn.png)